# Trouble with text and linecount from textblock in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, event-handling, line-count

In my code I'm trying to obtain a value from a textbox within my options window when my submit button is clicked. I know I need to covert the string into a double which I've done, but my problem is that distanceOption just get sets to 0.0 instead of the value the user puts into the text box. I think my trouble might be with the linecount of the textbox. My linecount variable keeps showing as -1 and not sure if that is what the value should be.

```
        void Options_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OptionsWindow optionsWindow = new OptionsWindow();
        optionsWindow.Show();
        optionsWindow.DistanceButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Distance_Clicked);
    }
    void Distance_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OptionsWindow optionsWindow = new OptionsWindow();
                  int lineCount = optionsWindow.DistanceBox.LineCount;
                 this.distanceOption = Convert.ToDouble(optionsWindow.DistanceBox.GetLineText(lineCount));

    }
```

If there is a better way to obtain the value from the textbox I would be open to that as well. Thanks!

Comment: If you create a new OptionsWindow in Distance_Clicked I guess DistanceBox.LineCount will be default. You need the original OptionsWindow where you clicked the DistanceButton.

Comment: @LPL Okay I get what you're saying. How do you suggest I get the optionsWindow from the Options_Clicked function in my Distance_clicked function?

Comment: It would be easy with MVVM. So all options seem to me like a hack. But you could move `OptionsWindow optionsWindow = new OptionsWindow();` out of the *Options_Clicked* handler so that you can reference it in *Distance_Clicked* handler too. But then you should register *optionsWindow.DistanceButton.Click* not in *Options_Clicked* or remove it after closing `OptionsWindow` otherwise you will get one more handler with every *Options_Click*.

Comment: @LPL thanks for the useful comments. your comments combined with Alan's answer solved my issue. thanks for swift responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    NewWindow optionsWindow = new NewWindow();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        optionsWindow.button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button1_Click);
        optionsWindow.Show();

    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double d = Convert.ToDouble(optionsWindow.textBox1.GetLineText(0));
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks this was easily formatted and solved my problem like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Create a proper ViewModel and use DataBinding:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyDouble}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public double MyDouble {get;set;} //Probably NotifyPropertyChanged
```

Comment: so I should replace my distanceOption which stored the double  with MyDouble throughout my program?

Comment: @averagepainter no, I'm talking about the need to use databinding instead of a procedural approach.